# How to add a folder (with help) to resources and how to work with it

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, system.diagnostics

I am working on a basic calculator and I want to have a **Help** in it. I've already written it in XHTML. It is about 30 html files and over 30 jpg files (everything in a folder '*help*').

Now a I would like to add this all into my Form. I don't know to add it to  the Resources and how to open the '*index.html*' file. I thing the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();` is used for such things, but I've never worked with it. The activation event for this will be click on the '*ToolStripMenuItem*'.

And my next question is: When I add all the files to the Project and publish the program (so it can be installed) would the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();` work for every user? Because I don't know in which folder would the program be install.

Comment: So you want to use the HTML in your WinForms application?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to open html file via WinForms app

Answer (score 1):

Okay you are confusing a number of different things here.
If you want to distribute your help as separate files, you don't want resources.

Just add a folder called help to your solution/project in the solution explorer, move the files into it with windows explorer. Then right click on the folder, choose add existing items, select all your files. Then the important bit on each on them in the solution explorer, select properties , and make sure sure they are copy always, or copy if newer. . Now when you build your project, the help files will go with it, but not in a help folder!
Then you can launch index.html (in the same folder as your app) and the app (almost certainly a browser) associated will fire up with that file.

Resources, would mean the files were not separate, they would be compiled in with your assembly, and you'd have to extract them  to launch externally or include your own help form with a be browser control. Have to be damn good reason to do all that work...

If you want one though. Right click on the project, select properties, select the resources tab.

Comment: OK, I've done it, but when I wanted to open the file index.html there was an error. The program can't find the file...

Comment: Just passing index.html? Few ways round that, but if it's in the same folder as your exe, then Process.Start(Path.Combine(System.Application.ExecutablePath,"index.html")) is one way. If not, ask another question and post some code.